# Getting the number of users per ip

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a query and I am stuck at one point and I am not really sure how to proceed. I have a table `users` that contains the following columns: `id`, `email` and `ip`. I want to get how many people log in from the same ip. This I am getting with the following request:

```
select count(distinct id) as countID
, ip
from users
group by ip
```

The end goal is to get a list of all the users for which the following condition is fulfilled - there are between 5 to 10 user per ip. and this is the part I am not sure about. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `having`:

```
select count(distinct id) as countID,
    ip
from users
group by ip
having count(distinct id) between 5 and 10
```