# Joining two tables in the most optimal way

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `users` that contains columns `id`, `ip` and `email`. I want to get how many of the users fulfill the following criteria - between 5 and 10 users logging in from the same ip. So far I have this query:

```
select count(distinct id) as countID,
    ip
from users
group by ip
having count(distinct id) between 5 and 10
```

I want to get the following columns - `id`, `email` and `countID` as a result. I was thinking of creating one temp table with the upper query and after that joining it with the `users` table using the `ip` as a key, but it takes too much time, because I have approximately 3 million rows. Can anyone think of a better solution?

Comment: Didnt you just ask this? Show us sample data and expected output? Because if 10 user login using same ip you have 10 emails.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza From the previous answer i got just the countID and ip. What I actually need is id, email and ountID in that order.

Comment: What is your second table? I only see one in this question.

Comment: The second table is 'users', and the first one is the temp table from the query

Comment: Your question doesnt make sense. You want ip with 5-10 user... But you also want email? what email? show us a sample of the data and desire output

Comment: Seems that more than 1 person is taking the same class and got the same homework question today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912268/getting-the-number-of-users-per-ip

Comment: @SeanLange could be :D

Comment: @SeanLange Or they are doing the homework together :P, but I never got a homework with 3 millions rows

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza people can be desperate nevertheless if it's homework or not :D

Comment: We had some stuff in college with around a million rows. We did our work against a server that everybody pulled data from. Seems kind of odd that the question is exactly the same for both people with something contrived business rules that also match exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by joining with original table on ip, you can get the details you need.

```
select u.*,
    u2.countID
from users u
join (
    select count(distinct id) as countID,
        ip
    from users
    group by ip
    having count(distinct id) between 5 and 10
    ) u2 on u.ip = u2.ip;
```